# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'prefix' of null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I make commands to change the prefix to the server, well, when I try to change, an error occurs, I looked in all the search engines, and I could not find the answer.

(node:4632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'prefix' of null

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'prefix',
    args: true,
    usage: '<префикс>',
    aliases: ['set-prefix', 's-prefix'],
    async execute(message, args) {
        const data = await Guild.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id });

        message.channel.send(`Новый префикс: \`${args[1]}\``);
        data.prefix = args[0];
        data.save;
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no prefix in the database. You can use findOneAndUpdate method:

```
await Guild.findOneAndUpdate({
guildID: message.guild.id //find the needed guild
}, {
guildID: message.guild.id, //update prefix
prefix: args[0]
}, {
upsert: true
});

message.channel.send(Новый префикс: \${args[1]}``);
```